# Ajax views with django

Tags: ajax, django, django-views, decorator, django-generic-views

I'm working on a pretty big project right now where every view should be accessible via a normal request and an ajax request via the same url. I'm looking for ideas on how to create a small framework to handle this in a very generic way. Depending on if the view is called via ajax or not it needs to render a different template and return a json instead of a `HttpResponse` object. I'd like to collect any ideas on this topic - the main goal should be not to avoid the dry principle and make code that is as reusable as possible. I was already considering different options as generic views, decorators on views etc, but I'm open to anything. So please let me hear your suggestions or point me towards any readymade snippets you know!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This article](http://webcloud.se/log/AJAX-in-Django-with-jQuery/) seems to be quite a good tutorial on how to work with both ajax and regular requests. The `request` object has a method `is_ajax()` which will look for `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH: XMLHttpRequest`. This will of course depend on these values being set correctly by the javascript sending the request.

From the article:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.core import serializers
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from your_app.models import ExampleModel

def xhr_test(request, format):
    obj = ExampleModel.objects.all()
    if request.is_ajax():
        data = serializers.serialize('json', obj)
        return HttpResponse(data,'json')
    else:
        return render_to_response('template.html', {'obj':obj}, context=...)
```

Or, you could use [django-piston](https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/wiki/Documentation) which is a RESTful framework for Django. I use this module in my project. You can define resources (sort of like views), and depending on either the mime-type or format passed to your url, it will emit either html, xml, or json. This will probably be the best way to go if every single view (or a large majority) need to be returned in different formats.

Comment: Well this is already the common way to do this, I'm looking for nice ways to not always have to repeat the switching between ajax/non-ajax requests in the view...

Comment: @lazer see the end of my answer which talks about django-piston. That allows you to return different responses based on mime-type or url parameters.

Comment: +1 for the idea of piston which is already part of the project, but it's only used as a rest api for "normal" use..

Comment: @lazer that's the good thing about piston, it's not just for JSON/XML responses. It can quite happily return HTML too if the mime-type is text/html =P

Comment: The article link is broken?

Answer (score 0):

I have used a decorator for this. Have the view return the context, the template, and an alternate template.

If the Ajax version wants to return data,  the third return value can be the data object to turn into JSON.